# Facebook Company Page post statistics in Google Sheets using API

Tags: json, google-sheets, facebook-graph-api

I'm already using the Facebook Marketing API to get real time ad performance into Google Sheets. However, I know that there is a Facebook Pages API and I'm able to fetch company page posts into Google Sheets but I can't find out how I can get statistics from these organic posts into Google Sheets.

Does anyone know how you can get this information from the API?
[Pages API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/)

So far I have been able to receive some information but nothing like reach, impressions, clicks etc. Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v17.0/insights